# Scraping 'Title' from image with Python and bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to scraping with Python and are in need of some assistance. I'm doing my own first project during my internship at a BI-consultant firm and are building a data model to use in Qlik Sense.

I've managed to scrape the names and values from: [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop) but now I would like to scrape the title of both club and country (which are visualised with a picture). Image scraping is something else (as I can understand, and a whole different set of code is needed). But I want the title, for example "France". Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Code updated with Pablos response. Now I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/cljkn/Desktop/Python scraper github/.vscode/Scraping Transfermarkt.py", line 33, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList,"Nationality":NationalityList})
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 64, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 365, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})

Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})

Nationality = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "flaggenrahmen"}, {"title"})
for nat in Nationality:
    img = nat.find('img')
    title = img.get('title')

PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []
NationalityList = []

for i in range(0,25):
    PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
    ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)
    NationalityList.append(Nationality[i].text)

NationalityList.append('title')

df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList,"Nationality":NationalityList})

df.head()

df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\cljkn\Desktop\Python scraper github\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)

print(df)
```

Any direct help with coding or source material would be most appreciated.

Comment: hi there Zakan - many thanks for your question it is great and i have learned lot of your idea and thoughts. Keep up the great work !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case, we need to use `regex`. because the `HTML` mixed up with some attributes.

For example :

```
title="https://www.transfermarkt.us/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop"/>
```

AND

```
title="France"
```

So we need to use `re` to match `title` which doesn't start with `http`:

```py
import re

for item in soup.findAll("img", class_="flaggenrahmen", title=re.compile("^(?!http).*")):
    print(item.get("title"))
```

Output will be:

```
France
England
Jamaica
Brazil
Senegal
Egypt
England
Belgium
Argentina
Spain
England
France
England
Portugal
France
Mali
Germany
France
Netherlands
Suriname
France
Slovenia
Belgium
Portugal
Netherlands
Germany
Argentina
Italy
Germany
Cote d'Ivoire
Spain
Brazil
```

Now we will go into another issue: where you have `players` with `two clubs` instead of `one`:

Such as:

[image]

> Now let's fix this. here's the full code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}
r = requests.get(
    "https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

names = []
values = []
nats = []


for name in soup.findAll("img", class_="bilderrahmen-fixed"):
    names.append(name.get("alt"))

for value in soup.findAll("td", class_="rechts hauptlink"):
    values.append(value.get_text(strip=True))

for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="zentriert"):
    inner_grp = []
    for item in td.findAll("img", class_="flaggenrahmen", title=re.compile("^(?!http).*")):
        #print(item.get('title'), end='')
        if item.get('title'):
            inner_grp.append(item.get('title'))
    if inner_grp:
        nats.append(inner_grp)

with open("result.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "Value", "Nat"])
    for a, b, c in zip(names, values, nats):
        writer.writerow([a, b, ", ".join(c)])

print("Done")
```

Output: [check-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/021267486fb6fd348a0119131b1ba451/result.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where in the code should I place that? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: With your solution I get:

NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zakan you welcome, please stop changing the question and updating it with title such as `solved` or copy `answer` to the `question`. since you already accepted my answer, so the question is listed as solved. no worries about that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Zakan you welcome, pay attention for the current answer, as i corrected the output of nats in one cell. [check](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/021267486fb6fd348a0119131b1ba451/result.csv)

Comment: Thanks. How would you go about getting the title of clubs aswell? It's also called title and is connected to a image.

Comment: @Zakan You've received the answer for the question which you've asked. but that's count as not logical to just go from problem to another. before writing your code. you should know what your expected output. for that, you should open new question. to maintain the order of the community.

Comment: @Zakan [code for clubs](https://bpaste.net/LTEQ) and [current-output](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ee32ce7d67405fbbe02716a1f3781896/result.csv)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm not use to asking questions here. Have a great day.

Comment: Thank you so much!  it also works for me - you are great - you guy rock!!! Thank you

Comment: @zero glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

With find_all you will get a list of "td" with class "flaggenrahmen". If you want the title you will need to loop over "Nationality" objects and .get('title').

**Edited solution:**

```
Nationality = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "flaggenrahmen"}, {"title"})
for nat in Nationality:
    img = nat.find('img')
    title = img.get('title')

PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []
NationalityList = []

for i in range(0,25):
    PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
    ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)
    NationalityList.append(nationality_list[i].text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where in the code should I place that? And how should I define Nationality? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Right below your code line: Nationality = pageSoup.find_all ("td", {"class": "flaggenrahmen"}, {"title"}). But you will need to store title in a list to preserve it.

Comment: Updated my code, could you take a look at the error message and make corrections? Thanks.

Comment: @Pablo before you post an answer to the `Original Poster` , kindly run your code and check the current output before building an advise.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη The code works perfectly but it is mixing the values ​​of 3 different lists ... that is why it does not work. I don't think it deserves a negative vote

Comment: @Zakan your your mistake is because the 3 lists you are going through with the 'i' have different length. Check the updated answer

Comment: I only get: 

File "c:/Users/cljkn/Desktop/Python scraper github/.vscode/texttest.py", line 29, in <module>
    NationalityList.append(NationalityList[i].text)
IndexError: list index out of range

Same error with your updated answer.

Comment: Players, Values or nationality_list have different length please check that